# Is antimatter present on Earth?

Tags: antimatter

As we all know, antimatter is present across all of space. Is it also present on Earth? If it is present on Earth then by the interaction of matter and antimatter, why don't we feel the energy around us?

Comment: I can't judge this, but there might be [anti-matter orbiting](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21128245-500-antiproton-ring-found-around-earth/) in Earth's magnetic radiation belts.

Comment: We certainly don't "know that antimatter is present across all space", in fact the universe seems to be made almost entirely of matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antimatter is present on Earth and is being naturally created all the time (by [Beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay)) as well as being created as product of cosmic ray collisions and in particle accelerators.

However the universe appears to be principally made of matter and so the antimatter thus created is annihilated: and although the production of antimatter through nuclear decay is essentially continuous, it is not of a high volume so the energy created in this way is not significant in the normal course of events. The real question is why is matter so much more abundant than antimatter: which is an open question though various theories have been proposed about why we might live in such a universe.

Comment: Antimatter has also been created artificially at [CERN Lab](http://home.web.cern.ch/about/updates/2014/01/antimatter-experiment-produces-first-beam-antihydrogen).